# How to remove duplicates based on partial match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I don't even know how to approach it as it feels too complex for my level.

Imagine courier tracking numbers and I am receiving some duplicated updates from upstream system in following format:

[image]

see attached image or a small piece of code that creates such table:

```
import pandas as pd
incoming_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Tracking ID' : ['4845','24345', '8436474', '457453', '24345-S2'],
    'Previous' : ['Paris', 'Lille', 'Paris', 'Marseille', 'Dijon'],
    'Current' : ['Nantes', 'Dijon', 'Dijon', 'Marseille', 'Lyon'],
    'Next' : ['Lyone', 'Lyon', 'Lyon', 'Rennes', 'NICE']
})
incoming_df
```

Obviously, tracking ID 24345-S2 (green arrow) is a duplication of 24345 (red arrow), however, it is not fully duplicated but a newer, updated location information (with history) for the parcel. How do I delete old line 24345 and keep new line 24345-S2 in the data set?

The length of tracking ID can be from 4 to 20 chars but '-S2' is always helpfully appended.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: New solution:

```
# extract duplicates
duplicates = df['Tracking ID'].str.extract('(.+)-S2').dropna()

# remove older entry if necessary
df = df[~df['Tracking ID'].isin(duplicates[0].unique())]
```

If the 1234-S2 entry is always lower in the DataFrame than the 1234 entry , you could do something like:

```
# remove the suffix from all entries
incoming_df['Tracking ID'] = incoming_df['Tracking ID'].apply(lambda x: x.split('-')[0])

# keep only the last entry of the duplicates
incoming_df = incoming_df.drop_duplicates(subset='Tracking ID', keep='last')
```

Comment: thank you for answering, but I can't be sure -S2 always comes second: it is unpredictable. Furthermore, I would like to keep -S2 in it just to keep that track that this line was a duplicate. Maybe there is another way...? but thank you again!

Comment: oh... just realised some tracking numbers can have a dash in the middle like 123-456-S2. Is there a way to make split to act from right to left?

Comment: [Yes, there is](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit)  ;)

Comment: This is fascinating!! It works like a charm! I am on the long journey to learn it as I never seen ~ tilda yet in Pandas statements and do not fully understand what these do, but will research. a follow-up question, if I may. I am noticing that some of the records have different suffixes: not only ...-S2 but also ...-S3 also and sometimes ...-B2-S2 and ...-M1-SR. How can I modify ('(.+)-S2') to match all these cases? Is this a regular expression format?

Comment: Yes, it's a regular expression. You could check out [https://regex101.com/](regex101) and try stuff out, so that you end up with something that works with all your data.